# Swift iOS 9 keyboard appear does not shift view up, but works in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield

Here's my code to shift the view up when a keyboard appears (also note that this view has a `CollectionView`):

```
if isKeyboardShowing {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
        if self.isCollectionViewBlockingInput() {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = -distanceShifted
            // Keyboard is shifted less because view already shifts by distance
            self.bottomConstraintForInput.constant = -keyboardViewEndFrame.height + distanceShifted
        } else {
            self.bottomConstraintForInput.constant = -keyboardViewEndFrame.height
        }
    })
}
```

Essentially the view's origin y is shifted up by a certain distance. This works for iOS 10, but in iOS 9 **when the view first loads and I open the keyboard for the first time, the view tries to shift up but fails. Instead, a black background appears to be shifted down momentarily, then disappears:

[image: Black part that appears momentarily then disappears in iOS 9]
This only happens on opening the keyboard **before scrolling the collection view**. Once I start scrolling the collection view, the error goes away and the keyboard shifts up correctly again.

**Also this error does not show up in iOS 10 at all.**

Comment: why don't you call the `layoutIfNeeded` method of `UIView` and use completion block for animations and write that inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    //Do your constraint change part here

}, completion: {bool in

        // Call here the layoutIfNeeded method
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

Comment: I realized it worked when I flipped the order and did self.view.layoutIfNeeded() first, then update my constraint in the completion. However there is a black background shown because the view moves up. How do I make the background behind the view white?